# Express in server to perform a database query

Tags: node.js, express

### I want to know how ExpressJS works in the server side

**I need some information on Server side, Main things are,As per my knowledge,**

- `ExpressJS` can perform all the functionalists of a PHP - - - IS it
  true ?
- My Client(Android) is ready to submit a POST request to Server
- If i can send one single information in the form of `(Key,value) pair`,
  can the Express accept that pair- -  Identify the value based on key
  and, to perform a `sql query` to Database based on the value received
  from android client?

If it can how it does it?

***MY Express Program ( It gives a Response without  scenario explained above - How to modify this program )***

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '*********',
    password: "*****",
    database: 'DB'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);
//
//REQUEST FOR FIRST REQUEST
//

app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

*Hope I am clear*
**Thanks** ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send information via query params or as part of the url path. If you send it as a query param, you can access it using

```
req.query.keyName;
```

If you want to send the value as part of the url, you'll have to add a route to accept it. You can accept variable content in a url by using the `:keyName` form. Express will capture it in req.params. So it would look a little like this:

```
app.get('/some/url/:keyName', function(req, res, next){
    var keyName = req.params.keyName;
    // . . .
});
```

Then you can send your http request to '/some/url/someKeyValue' and the variable `keyName` will then be equal to whatever you add after /some/url/.

If you're POSTing data in the body of the request, access it with `req.body.keyName`.

EDIT: Here's an attempt at using the original code. Note that I'm still making up values and guessing at what the intent is.

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '*********',
    password: "*****",
    database: 'DB'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);

//
//REQUEST FOR FIRST REQUEST
//

app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name = ' . request.body.name, function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                name_of_restaurants = rows;
                callback();
            });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                RestaurantTimings = rows;
                callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
    ], function ( error, results ) {
        response.json({
            'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
            'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
        });
    } );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

But you should really not query directly like that because of SQL injection. I've never used MySQL from node, but I'm *sure* there is some way to use parameterized queries. Hope this is more helpful.

Also, I'm assuming that the data will be passed in the request body, since you said you are ready to POST to the server.

Comment: **"function(req, res, next)"** ..... Quoting the first two are request and response ..... What is "Next" you have mentioned ? ...... also can you edit the program asked in the question ... with your solution .... It will provide more clarity for a newbie, Thanks

Comment: All express route handler calllbacks accept three parameters - a request object, a response object, and an additional callback. You can use `next` if you want to match multiple routes. That's useful if you have global route handlers (like authentication) that should happen for every request. At the end of those handlers, you just call `next()` or `next(err)` (if there is an error and you have error handler middleware) and control gets passed to the next matching route or handler.

Comment: I didn't use the original code because it was not clear from the code or post what key/value pair the server is expecting or how the database will use those. I can make that up I suppose, but it will still be more representative than anything.

Comment: Ok Thanks for providing clarity, So just ... im thinking  code must be **app.get(---------){ var keyName=req.params.keyValue;});** right ? ......... because we need to match the condition based on the KeyValue by extracting with the help of KeyName

Comment: `keyName` was just an example. You use whatever's in the route. For example: `app.get('/restaurant/:id', function(req, res, next){...})` and then access it with `req.params.id` or `app.get('/restaurant/:name', function(req, res, next){...})` and access it with `req.params.name`, etc. It's really handy. If you haven't checked out the documentation on express, I linked to it above. It can tell you a lot more than I can in a 600 character comment.